# Does equality of operators on vacuum imply equality of operators on the whole space?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, lorentz-symmetry

Consider a field operator $\Phi(x)$ which generates states from the vacuum such as
$$ \tag 1 | x \rangle = \Phi(x) | 0 \rangle.$$
Consider also how a translation is implemented on such a state:
$$ \tag 2 | x + y \rangle = e^{iyP} | x \rangle,$$
where $P^\mu$ are the generators of translations.
Now consider the following chain of identies, in which only **(1)** and **(2)** are used:
$$ \tag 3 \Phi(x+y) | 0 \rangle
= | x + y \rangle
= e^{iyP} | x \rangle
= e^{iyP} \Phi(x) | 0 \rangle. $$

From this, I would be tempted to conclude that the transformation rule for $\Phi(x)$ is
$$ \tag 4 \Phi(x+y) = e^{iyP} \Phi(x),$$
while we know that the correct transformation rule is
$$ \tag 5 \Phi(x+y) = e^{iyP} \Phi(x) e^{-iyP}.$$
What is wrong with the above reasoning?

Comment: Hint: Demand $\Phi(x)\lvert \psi \rangle \mapsto \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}yP}(\Phi(x)\lvert \psi \rangle)$ for a state that is not the vacuum, and use that $\lvert \psi \rangle \mapsto \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}yP}\lvert \psi \rangle$. You don't see the right transformation in your argument because the vacuum is translation invariant by definition.

Comment: @ACuriousMind thanks for the comment. I suspected something like that. The answer to my question is then: it is not true that **(3)** implies **(4)** because mathematically the $|0\rangle$s on the LHS and the one on the RHS are not the same thing? However, we do identify them as representing the same physical state. Is it then the case that what we usually call "the vacuum state $|0\rangle$" is infact something like an equivalence class of states?

Comment: $(3)$ does not imply $(4)$ because equality of operators on the vacuum does not imply equality of operators on the whole space. $(3)$ is consistent with both $(4)$ and $(5)$ because, as I said, the vacuum is translation invariant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert #1 \rangle} \newcommand{\iex}[1]{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}#1}} \newcommand{\miex}[1]{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}#1}}$Your $(3)$ does not imply $(4)$, since equality of operators on *one* state - the vacuum in this case - does not imply the equality of the operators on the whole space.

To get the correct transformation, consider an arbitrary state $\ket{\psi}$ transforming under a translation by $y$ as $\ket{\psi} \mapsto \iex{yP}\ket{\psi}$. Since $\Phi(x)\ket{\psi}$ is also a state, we must have $\Phi(x)\ket{\psi} \mapsto \iex{yP}(\Phi(x)\ket{\psi})$. But we also know that the transformation works on the individual parts as

$$ \Phi(x)\ket{\psi} \mapsto \Phi(x+y)\iex{yP}\ket{\psi}$$

and since the momentum operator and the field do not necessarily commute, we see that, certainly, $\Phi(x+y) = \iex{yP}\Phi(x)\miex{yP}$ is a prescription that yields the desired transformation rule for *all* states $\ket{\psi}$.

Note: This is not a wrong prescription in case of the vacuum, since the vacuum is translation invariant, so $(4)$ and $(5)$ have the same effect in that case.